# How to order selection from database alphabetically?

Tags: mysql

From this code:

```
SELECT * 
FROM  members 
ORDER BY  @ALPHABETICALLY
```

How to order it in this type?
Thanks.

Comment: What fields are in "members"?  You need to choose a field (or fields) to sort on and provide that to your ORDER BY statement.

Comment: fields are id, password,username,salt,email,date

Comment: Crazy, a short search with your question in the header and I found the answer http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_orderby.asp. Doesn't look like you really searched for your problem before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have `name` column in that table the query would be:

```
SELECT * 
FROM  members 
ORDER BY  name ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ..., last_name, first_name, ...
FROM tbl
ORDER BY last_name, first_name;
```

VARCHAR columns in ORDER BY are sorted alphabetically; INT columns are sorted numerically.

ASC and DESC are optional suffixes for "ascending" and "descending":

```
`ORDER BY date DESC`
```

to see the latest first.

Answer (score 0):

SQL queries require you to provide a column to sort on -- otherwise, your database engine would have no idea which data to use.  This is an error because the behavior that would result is almost certainly not what you would be expecting!

Per your comment, you want to sort alphabetically on "name".  Presuming that name is a character column, sorting on it will result in an alphabetical sort.  So the query you're looking for is:

```
SELECT * 
FROM  members 
ORDER BY username ASC
```

ASC is optional and the default; it means to sort in ascending order.  To sort Z -> A, you can specify DESC instead.  You can specify a different column (say, email) to sort by it instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM `Table_Name`
ORDER BY `Your_Column_name_1` ASC, `Your_Column_name_2` DESC
```